# Odd Logstash date parsing error

Tags: date, filter, logstash

I'm getting the following error from Logstash:

> {:timestamp=>"2013-12-30T17:05:01.968000-0800", :message=>"Failed parsing date from field", :field=>"message", :value=>"2013-12-30 17:04:59,539.539 INFO  14282:140418951137024 [foo.lib.base.onResults:152] -- /1.12/media - \"getMediaStoreUrl\": , 10.101.AA.BB, 10.101.19.254 took 0.170675992966, returning https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/foo/customerMedia/1009238911/23883995/image?Signature=%2BfXqEdNWtWdhwzi%&*YEGJSDDdDFF%3D&Expires=1388455499&AWSAccessKeyId=NOIMNOTTHATSTUPID>, , >>>", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-12-30 17:04:59,539.539 INFO  14282:140418951137024..." is malformed at ".539 INFO  14282:140418951137024...", :level=>:warn}

The error is obviously about the date format, which comes to me as:

```
2013-12-30 17:04:59,539.539 INFO 14282:140418951137024...
```

And my pattern is as follows:

```
    date {
        match => ["message", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    }
```

I read up on the [Joda-Time Library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) and I think I've got the format correct above.  It's odd to me that the error message contains the doubled SSS (milliseconds) portion: ",539.539" (our logs output that way for some reason).  I deliberately didn't put the second portion ".539" in my pattern because I want it ignored.

I am also successfully using the following pattern in another filter:

```
(?<pylonsdate>%{DATESTAMP}\.[0-9]+)
```

I'm just not exactly sure where this error is coming from.  Any ideas what I need to do to correct this?  Do I need to mutate @timestamp?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because the other information in "message" field will make date api parsing error. 
Ex: INFO 14282:140418951137024...

You can use grok api to get the date and then use date api/

```
grok { 
     match => ["message","%{DATESTAMP:logtime}\.[0-9]+"]
}
date {
     match => ["logtime","YY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
}
```

I have tried this configuration with your log. It works on me. Hope this can help you .

Comment: The problem I'm having is more complex than initially stated. Yes, the above answer works, thank you. But I'm using a custom patterns file and struggling with defining the same pattern there.  Thanks for this answer, it definitely helped me hunt the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it may be due to [this bug](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/1700) in the Logstash *date* filter.

I have a much simpler *date* filter that generates the same error, and came across your question while searching for the answer.